# How to Draw a triangle shape in python?

Tags: python

I want to draw the shape of a triangle using python. I have already drawn the shape of circle but I cannot draw the triangle. Could someone please help me with this?

This is my code for the circle and I want to use the same type of code for the triangle.

```
import graphics
import random
win=graphics.GraphWin("Exercise 7",500,500)
win.setBackground("white")
for i in range(1000):
    x=random.randint(0,500)
    y=random.randint(0,500)
    z=random.randint(1,100)
    point = graphics.Point(x,y)
    circle=graphics.Circle(point,z)
    colour=graphics.color_rgb(random.randint(0,255),
                              random.randint(0,255),
                              random.randint(0,255))
    circle.setFill(colour)
    circle.draw(win)
win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered that a triangle is a three-sided `Polygon`?

Comment: So how can i use that one..  Could you please illustrate or use that function on the above program ??

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node9.html). This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: how to install graphics module? `pip install graphics` causes `No matching distribution found for graphics` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should create a single triangle, with random vertices (corners):

```
vertices = []
for i in range(3):                         # Do this 3 times
    x = random.randint(0, 500)             # Create a random x value
    y = random.randint(0, 500)             # Create a random y value
    vertices.append(graphics.Point(x, y))  # Add the (x, y) point to the vertices
triangle = graphics.Polygon(vertices)      # Create the triangle
triangle.setFill(colour)
triangle.draw(win)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Man u r awesome.. Actuall i dont use the way u gave bt i have got the idea.. Thanks a lot !!